# What are the equivalent of CGContext.translateBy/scaleBy in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have a piece of Swift code that I would like to convert to c# in Xamarin.iOS.

```
func test(source: UIImage)
{
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    if let cgImage = source.cgImage {
            context.translateBy(x: 0, y: source.size.height)
            context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: source.size.width, height: source.size.height)
            context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
        }
    ....
}
```

Here what I've got right now:

```
public void Test(UIImage source)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    var cgImage = source.CGImage;
    if (cgImage != null)
    {
       context.TranslateCTM(tx: 0, ty: source.Size.Height);
       context.ScaleCTM(sx: 1.0f, sy: -1.0f);
       var rect = new CGRect(x: 0.0f, y: 0.0f, width: source.Size.Width, height: source.Size.Height);
       context.DrawImage(rect, cgImage);
    }
    ....
}
```

I have absolutely no idea if `translateBy` becomes `TranslateCTM` and `scaleBy` becomes `ScaleCTM'.

I just can say that the result I expect is not there.

---

EDIT : This is [the full code](https://qiita.com/cayozin/items/fc70a367cd03b8572c83) I'm trying to convert.
Basically It allows me to add a notification badge to an image.

The final result I get is an image with only the notification badge, the source image has completely gone.

Without the badge:

[image]

With the badge:

[image]

---

EDIT 2 :
The code is correct per @Sweeper second comment.

The problem is that my image is a png that needed a tint color to be applied:

```
public void Test(UIImage source, UIColor tintColor = null)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    var cgImage = source.CGImage;
    if (cgImage != null)
    {
       context.TranslateCTM(tx: 0, ty: source.Size.Height);
       context.ScaleCTM(sx: 1.0f, sy: -1.0f);
       var rect = new CGRect(x: 0.0f, y: 0.0f, width: source.Size.Width, height: source.Size.Height);
       context.DrawImage(rect, cgImage);
       if ( tintColor != null)
       {
           context.SetFillColor(tintColor.CGColor);
           context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.SourceAtop);
           context.FillRect(rect);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the result that you expect and the result you got?

Comment: The [Objective-C version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455286-cgcontexttranslatectm?language=objc) of that is called `CGContextTranslateCTM`, so `context.TranslateCTM` is probably the right method here. The Xamarin.iOS name is usually closer to the Objective name.